# What can cause latency spikes during AF_UNIX file descriptor sharing?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, latency, unix-socket

I have a long running server process, and a short running client process communicating over AF_UNIX sockets on Linux.

- The client connects to the server and sends a request, in return the server shares a batch of 1000 file descriptors with the client. The file descriptors are sent in short AF_UNIX messages with 1 ancillary buffer (containing 250fds) attached to each message. So the 1000 fds are sent in 4 messages (4x250)
- The client the does some processing with the fds and closes all 1000
- This is procedure is repeated 4 additional times (5x1000 fds processed overall), then the client process quits

Functionally everything works fine, the client gets its 5x1000 fds and does its job.

Latency wise the 1st 1000 is always much slower than the later 4 batches. One transaction (1 request, then 1000 fds sent back in 4 response messages) usually takes in 5ms, 3 of which is spent in the server preparing the fds. For the first batch on the other hand the 2 `recvmsg` calls block for about 40ms each.

It only happens on the first batch, the next 4x1000 are always fine. And it happens every time I start the client. As if something "warms up" in the client process. But I can't figure out as time is not spent in my code, but a syscall.

Looking at the server logs I don't see any issue, the server always prepares the 4 response messages of the batch in 3ms. The system is not loaded, there's plenty of RAM and CPU resources available. The processes are running on WSL2 if that makes significance.

**I would like to understand what happens in the 1st batch**. What can I look for (kernel params, tracing/debugging tools, etc)?

---

Update:
I did some experiments: allocated 1000 fds at client startup by calling dup(1) 1000 times then closing all fds. Now this step suffers the same delay as the 1st batch previously, and all 5 batches run in 5ms. So the problem is not related to AF_UNIX sockets, instead it's about allocating a large number of file descriptors in a short time.